# Store business dates as PHP variables. Update automatically

Tags: php, variables, date

I would like to create 5 variables. They should hold the `date('Y-m-d')` values of each business day in the current week number.

For example (this week)

```
$mon_value = 2012-07-30
$tue_value = 2012-07-31
$wed_value = 2012-08-01
$thu_value = 2012-08-02
$fri_value = 2012-08-03
```

And this should update automatically when the week number changes.

How would I achieve this? I am fairly new to PHP programming...

Comment: How exactly do you mean? `date()` is always from the perspective of the current moment, so you don't need to worry about that not updating. Or do you mean you want to manually change week? We need more info on what you're trying to do - please edit the question.

Comment: Do you mean get the date value from Monday to Friday of current week?

Comment: Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) that has method [add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) to add date. use cron-job to update dates.

Comment: @xdazz It should update the dates based on the week that is current. For example now it's 31, next is 32 then there should be new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a nifty function called strtotime, which can be used in the following way:

```
strtotime('Monday')
```

Combine that with the date function and you can have the date of each day:

```
$mon_value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Monday'));
$tue_value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Tuesday'));
// so forth...
```

[strtotime documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that i use to find the first and the last day of a "calendar" numbered week :

```
//For this week, we are the 2012-07-30
$week_number = date('W', mktime(12, 0, 0 , 07, 30, 2012));
$monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($expl[0]."W".$week_number.'1'));
$sunday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($expl[0]."W".$week_number.'7'));
```

I let you make the loop and insert it into an Array instead of 7 vars !